# Diagram type for visualising threads and synchronization among them

Tags: oop, visualization, diagram

The other day I was writing a [sequence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram) on the blackboard, which is really good for visualising interaction between different components. However I realised that we had several different threads interacting (synchronizing and signalling), and I had no good way to visualise that.

**Do you know a diagram type that is good for visualising interactions between different threads?**

I am not looking for a drawing program or anything, just a diagram type I can memorize and use on the blackboard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Activity Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram)s?  They have specific syntax for showing parallel activities, including messaging and synchronisation.  You can use swimlanes (or partitions) to show different threads if required.

hth.